# "Tap to focus" to "auto focus" when content in camera view changed. Logic like in the stock Camera app or the UIImagePickerController for iOS?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, key-value-observing, autofocus

How do I handle the switch from "tap to focus" at a specific POI back to "auto focus" state automatically after lost focus when the contents in the view changed? If you notice the focus behavior in the stock Camera app or the UIImagePickerController, after you tap focus some area and you move the phone away, the camera can automatically switch to continuous auto focus at the center of the screen.

I need some more flexibility than what a UIImagePickerController can provide, so I need to use AVFoundation to mimic the UIImagePickerController behavior first...

Comment: This is a good observation, many posts only implemented the "Tap to focus", but forgot to restore to "auto focus", thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Are you sure the camera by default focuses at the center of the screen? Cameras have sophisticated autofocus algorithms that try to decide what's interesting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds very complex at first to me... but it turned super simple, Apple already did the 99% of work for us. All you need to do is to set "[subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html)" on and register KVO on "AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification"! On the iOS 6.1 docs:

> The value of this property indicates whether the receiver should
>   monitor the video subject area for changes, such as lighting changes,
>   substantial movement, and so on. If subject area change monitoring is
>   enabled, the capture device object sends an
>   AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification whenever it detects a
>   change to the subject area, at which time an interested client may
>   wish to re-focus, adjust exposure, white balance, etc.
>
> Before changing the value of this property, you must call
>   lockForConfiguration: to acquire exclusive access to the device’s
>   configuration properties. If you do not, setting the value of this
>   property raises an exception. When you are done configuring the
>   device, call unlockForConfiguration to release the lock and allow
>   other devices to configure the settings.
>
> You can observe changes to the value of this property using key-value
>   observing.

(Even better, you don't need to handle many corner cases. What if the device is in the middle of "adjustingFocus" at a POI and the content changed? You don't want the device fall back to auto focus at the center, and want the focus action to finish. The "area did change notification" is only triggered after the focus is done.)

Some sample code snippet from my project. (The structure follows the official AVFoundation example AVCam, so you can put them in easily and try out):

```
// CameraCaptureManager.m

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDevice *backFacingCamera;

- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){

        // TODO: more of your setup code for AVFoundation capture session
        for (AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
            if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack){
                self.backFacingCamera = device;
            }
        }

        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

        void (^subjectAreaDidChangeBlock)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification *notification) {

            if (self.videoInput.device.focusMode == AVCaptureFocusModeLocked ){
                // All you need to do is set the continuous focus at the center. This is the same behavior as
                // in the stock Camera app
                [self continuousFocusAtPoint:CGPointMake(.5f, .5f)];
            }
        };

        self.subjectAreaDidChangeObserver = [notificationCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification
                                                                            object:nil
                                                                             queue:nil
                                                                        usingBlock:subjectAreaDidChangeBlock];

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPathAdjustingFocus options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    // Remove the observer when done
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self.deviceOrientationDidChangeObserver];
}

- (BOOL) setupSession{
    BOOL sucess = NO;

    if ([self.backFacingCamera lockForConfiguration:nil]){
        // Turn on subject area change monitoring
        self.backFacingCamera.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = YES;
    }

    [self.backFacingCamera unlockForConfiguration];

    // TODO: Setup add input etc...

    return sucess;
}
```

Comment: Why you check for focusMode == AVCaptureFocusModeLocked before calling continuousFocusAtPoint:CGPointMake(.5f, .5f)? I think that default behavior is opposite - setting focus in the center of screen if it is not locked by the user.

Comment: @Timur Watch out this happens in "subjectAreaDidChangeBlock", which means after focus locking, contents in the camera changed, default behavior is focus at the center. You can check by first tapping focus on the corner, then move your camera to a different subject, camera will focus to center

Comment: camera will focus to center - yes, that's right. But if user manually locked focus by long tap, you should not change it. That's default behavior. Right check here is device.focusMode != AVCaptureFocusModeLocked

Comment: That's not the default behavior, even user manually lock focus at somewhere, it's not forever. After the scene in the camera changed, camera will know  your subject changed, and re-focus to center. You can verify with your phone. That's the whole point of this question and the code.

Comment: Just checked, no, at least at my 4s with ios7 it does not unlocking automatically on subject changes until you tap screen again.

Comment: Interesting... my 5 does for iOS 6 and 7. Even 4s does not do this, it's reasonable to re-focus to center after content changed, after all your subject is no longer on the area you tapped, the camera has to have some area in focus, center is the safest choice.

Comment: Are u sure u see yellow AF/AE LOCKED label at the top of the screen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38641/discussion-between-phantomlimb-and-timur)

Comment: What is this `continuousFocusAtPoint` method?

Comment: Is there a Swift version? Thanks!

Comment: faviomob is correct. If you just tap to focus and meter, it's reset when the scene changes. If you press and hold, you get the AF/AE locked label, then it doesn't change when the scene changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the comment of the answer of @Xiaochao Yang 's and I want to add some explain of the code `CGPointMake(.5f, .5f)`. According to the apple's API ,the CGPoint you set to the camera is in the range of {0,0} to the {1,1} at the same time the `CGPointMake(.5f, .5f)`means the center of the camera.

> This property represents a CGPoint where {0,0} corresponds to the top left of the picture area, and {1,1} corresponds to the bottom right in landscape mode with the home button on the right—this applies even if the device is in portrait mode

From [AVCaptureDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/focusPointOfInterest)